# React Native how to setState on a componentWillMount method

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an api that gets data and I want to loop thru that data on render it on a list, but setState inside the componentWillMount is undefined. I'm getting this error

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: this.setState is not a function. (In 'this.setState({]

class FoodsScreen extends Component {   
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.componentWillMount = this.componentWillMount.bind(this)
  }

  state = {
    cuisine: undefined,
    cuisines: undefined
  };

  componentWillMount() {

    firebase.firestore().collection("cuisines").get().then(function (querySnapshot) {

      const elements = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        elements.push({ id: doc.id, name: doc.data().name });
      });
      this.setState({ cuisines: elements})

    });

  }


render() {
   return(
       <React.Fragment>
          <Item picker style={{ marginLeft: 15 }}>
              <Label style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Cuisine</Label>
              <Picker
                mode="dropdown"
                iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                style={{ width: undefined }}
                placeholder="Select your"
                placeholderStyle={{ color: "#bfc6ea" }}
                placeholderIconColor="#007aff"
                selectedValue={this.state.cuisine}
                onValueChange={this.onValueChange2.bind(this)}
              >
                {this.state.cuisines.map((cuisine, index) => {
                  return <Picker.Item label={cuisine.name} key={index} value={cuisine.id} />
                })}
              </Picker>
            </Item>
       </React.Fragment>
   )
}
```

how can i get the list of cuisines and render the data on my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to solve your problem.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    //                                                     arrow function
    firebase.firestore().collection("cuisines").get().then(querySnapshot => {

      const elements = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        elements.push({ id: doc.id, name: doc.data().name });
      });
      this.setState({ cuisines: elements})

    });

  }
```